# Build error 'CodedUITestAttribute could not be found'

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2019

I am getting a build error in VSTS 2019 and VSTS 2017 while checking in my code:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodedUITestAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUIFramework
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common

Comment: I'm guessing your build server does not have Visual Studio installed, so these assemblies are not present.

Comment: This might be what you need to install: [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: Are you using Enterprise license of Visual studio?

Comment: What is the project type in which you're trying to use CodedUI?